# overflow in conversion from ‘int’ to ‘char’ changes C

Tags: c, linux, variables

Whenever I am running this code it works perfect:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    char a = 's';

    printf("Value of a is: %c \n",a);

    return 0;

}
```

Result:

> The value is: s

But whenever I add another character:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

char a = 'ss';

printf("Value of a is: %c \n",a);

return 0;

}
```

It Shows this Error:

> Error:
>
> ```
> test.c: In function ‘main’:
> test.c:5:11: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
>     5 |  char a = 'ss';
>     |           ^~~~
> test.c:5:11: warning: overflow in conversion from ‘int’ to ‘char’ changes value from ‘29555’          to ‘115’ [-Woverflow]
> ```

I want to call "*Hello World*" from the variable a

Comment: What do you expect it to do for `'ss'`?

Comment: `char` as the name suggests is meant to hold **one** character.  If you want to store two characters, normally you would use a string, which is an array of `char`.

Comment: Show me "The value is: ss"

Comment: You can't store _multiple_ chars in a single char.

Comment: A Sample of code which print Hello World

Comment: What Should I do to print more than 1 char

Comment: `char` holds one, and only ever one, character. `char*` can hold more *if* there's memory allocated to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to work with strings instead of `char`s. A `char` represents just a single character. If you want multiple characters, you need a string. In C, strings are represented by `char *`. So you might try

```
char *a = "ss";
printf("Value of a is: %s\n", a);
```

Notice the double quotes around a string as opposed to the single quotes around a character. Also notice `%s` instead of `%c` in the format string.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes are for an individual character.  Multiple characters should not (in most cases) appear in single quotes.  If you want a string you need double quotes.

You also need to change the type of the variable you assign it to to `char *` and use `%s` to print it.

```
char *a = "ss";
printf("Value of a is: %s \n",a);
```

Answer (score 0):

`char` can store only one character. In order to hold a string, you need a char array

> Strings are actually one-dimensional array of characters terminated by
> a null character '\0'. Thus a null-terminated string contains the
> characters that comprise the string followed by a null.

A working piece of code would be

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *a = "Hello World";
    printf("Value of a is: %s \n", a);

    return (0);
}
```